# Computing time/duration in Golang templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I have a structure that gets rendered via `template`. e.g.:

```
type Foo struct {
  Created time.Time
  ...
}
```

I pass this value to a template, and I'd like to this rendered see:

```
  Created at 2022-11-22 9:50 (0d1h12m34s ago)
```

Displaying the timestamp (and formatting it) is easy enough, but I can't find a way to calculate the interval.

```
Created at {{.Created}} ({{???}} ago)
```

In go, this would be accomplished by `time.Since(foo.Created)` which returns a `Duration`, and then I can convert duration to string in various ways.

But doing the calculation in the template itself does not seem possible:

```
function "time" not defined
```

Or is it?
Can't find any information that explicitly tells me that `time` (or other arbitrary functions) are never ever allowed in templates. So I don't know if I'm just calling it wrong.

(I know I could create a new `FooTemplateValue` from a `Foo` add that field, so the template can render the duration as-is. I was just trying to avoid it if I can and use the actual object as-is).

Comment: @mkopriva thank you, both suggestions seem viable answers to my specific problems. If you post them as answers rather than comment I'd be happy to mark them as valid solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register a custom template function using [`template.FuncMap`](https://pkg.go.dev/html/template@go1.19.3#FuncMap), then you can invoke that function inside the template just like you would invoke a builtin function.

```golang
template.New("").Funcs(template.FuncMap{
    "dur_until_now": func(t time.Time) time.Duration {
        return time.Now().Sub(t)
    },
}).Parse(`{{ dur_until_now .Created }}`)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/wM2f1oDFtDr

---

Or you can declare a custom time type and have that type implement a method that produces the desired value, then you can invoke that method inside the template directly on the field.

```golang
type MyTime struct{ time.Time }

func (t MyTime) DurUntilNow() time.Duration {
    return time.Now().Sub(t.Time)
}

// ...
.Parse(`{{ .Created.DurUntilNow }}`)
```

https://go.dev/play/p/3faW4nTzK3-

Comment: Both great options, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Looks like you need to initialize the Created field with time.Now()

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

type Foo struct {
    Created time.Time
    // ...
}

func main() {
    x := Foo{Created: time.Now()}

    fmt.Println(time.Since(x.Created))
}
```

Comment: My question is about invoking `time._` functions from a template, not about initializing a struct.

Comment: answer is not appropriate , questioner ask different thing